# Login to Provisioning Portal using XCode

Tags: xcode, provisioning, portal, organizer

hope someone is able to help me with this. I am trying to use automatic provisioning through xcode's organizer. Whenever I click on it, it prompts me to log in to the developer portal. I entered my credentials but it keeps popping up, as though my credentials are incorrect. I have checked that my credentials are correct because I am able to log in to the portal through the website.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Check your spelling again and be sure that connections to and from Xcode are not being blocked locally or on your network. If you continue to have problems, I'd recommend a full reinstall of Xcode.

Comment: I checked that my connection is not blocked. I'll try reinstalling in a while.. Thanks!

Comment: Reinstalling Xcode works. Thanks!